# How can i see the php result in div

Tags: php, html

Ok i am trying to load the result of the php on submit to div. For some reason it wont work the way i would do it, the way i did  loads the entire php script ahead witch i don't want. so is there another way to do it?

```
function loginForm(){
    echo'
    <div id="loginform">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        <input type="text" phone="phone" id="name" />
        <input type="text" email="email" id="name" /> 
        <input type="submit" name="enter" id="enter" value="Enter" />
    </form>    <div id="errornofill">  </div>';
}
```

I need the result of the errors above to be in **errornofill** i did try something like

in html `'.$errornofill.' </div>';`
in php  `$errornofill = echo "<br /><span class=error>Please type in your Email</span><br />";`

But culdint use it be cuz it will lode the entire php code ahead if i tryd something else it wouldn't show at all. if that makes sense i personally don't know

So i made this. but how do i get the result to be in the div?

```
if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
                $_SESSION['name'] = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    if ((empty($name))) { echo  '<br /><span class="error">Please type in a name</span><br />', {id: id});
    }
    if ((empty($phone))) { echo  '<br /><span class="error">Please type in your phone</span><br />';
    }
    if ((empty($email))) { echo  '<br /><span class="error">Please type in your Email</span><br />'; 
    }

// Alot of cods here 
$name = $_SESSION['name']; // Just to see what lods i added this
    }
    else 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of echoing your error, put them in a var, and later on output them.

```
$error_output = "";
if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
                $_SESSION['name'] = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    if ((empty($name))) {

 $error_output .= '<br /><span class="error">Please type in a name</span><br />', {id: id});
    }
    if ((empty($phone))) { 
$error_output .= '<br /><span class="error">Please type in your phone</span><br />';
    }
    if ((empty($email))) { 
$error_output .= '<br /><span class="error">Please type in your Email</span><br />'; 
    }


$name = $_SESSION['name']; // Just to see what lods i added this
    }

 echo '<div id="loginform">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        <input type="text" phone="phone" id="name" />
        <input type="text" email="email" id="name" /> 
        <input type="submit" name="enter" id="enter" value="Enter" />
    </form>    <div id="errornofill">' . $error_output . '</div>';
```

Comment: Good it work love your answer i will work on some php erorrs i got. if i have 2 if(isset($_POST['enter'])){ will it efect the other one? hmmm i think i will try to repair some codes before i go ahead and make others do my job lmoh but yea that quchtion will help me understand if i shuld go on or stay here. thanks

Comment: I just want to personally thank you for this. i played around with the code i fix all errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your files and rename your template file or where your div mark-up is to `.php` in extension and use a php include.

```
 <?php include 'path/to/your/php/script.php'; ?>
```

For more information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: I don't exactly understand how it would help. i know what include is the html and php is on the same page. how will it help if i separate the code into include file? can you explain this a bit better? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable e.g. $errOutput before the checks, then instead of echo-ing the error you do

```
$errOutput .= '<span>....;
```

This will create a string with all your error warnings which you can output as follows:

```
echo '<div id="errornofill">'.$errOutput.'</div>';
```

Comment: I tried that already.  if i put the html in between or after the long php code, the html form wont show up. this would of bean a grate answer. But my long crazy code wont talrate it bing at the end. +1 for you tho :)

Comment: I don't really understand your question then. Are you aware that a php scripts always generates all output in one go? If you reload or submit a form it will show everything again. Please edit your answer to show the structure of your php script, I think that's where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can open and close php tags whenever you want, that way you can first calculate all you need, and then echo it in the HTML, or do some validations too.

For example:

```
<?php 
$number = 4;
if($number == 4) 
{
?>
<h1>This will be visible if conditions met.</h1>
<?php
} // Close the if sentence.
else {
?>
<h1>This will be visible if conditions don't met.</h1>
<?php
} // Close else.
?>
```

So basically you can just put your form and check for errors before showing anything and according to results you can act.

And like I said before, you can place your php tags anywhere you want, here's another example:

```
<?php
$name = 'John';
?>
<h1>Hello my name is <?php echo $name; ?></h1>
```

You might want to check if the form has been submitted first, so if it was not submitted you can show it, or else program its behavior.